# why isn't const keyword applied to a structural binding to std::tie()?

Tags: c++

The first case: `const` keyword is applied to the variables, `m` and `n` so that their type is `const int&`.

```
int a[2] = {1, 2};
const auto& [m, n] = a;
```

The second case: a type of `m` and `n` is `int&` because `std::tie()` generates lvalue references.

```
int i = 5, j = 6;
auto [m, n] = std::tie(i, j);
```

The third case (The problem case): However, a type of the variables, `m` and `n` is not `const int&`, but `int&`.

```
int x = 5, y = 6;
const auto [m, n] = std::tie(x, y);
```

In the third case, why `const` is not applied?

Comment: You understand that `const auto` isn't applied directly to `m`,`n`, but rather to a single hidden variable holding the tuple? `m`,`n` then become (somewhat magical) references to the members of that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is equivalent to

```
const std::tuple<int&, int&> t = {x, y};
int& m = std::get<0>(t);
int& n = std::get<1>(t);
```

Declaring the tuple const doesn't make their reference members const. The example below is a valid code, maybe more clear

```
struct A {
  A(int& m) : m(m) {}
  int& m;
};

int main() {
  int x = 5;
  const A a(x);
  a.m = 0;
}
```

A reference refers a non const variable. Applying const to a reference doesn't make it a reference to a const variable. Similar: `int* const p;` - const pointer can refer a non const location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Then, what makes the first case a reference to the array `a`? If `const` and `reference` is applied to a temporary variable, the type of variables in the first case should be `int`.

Comment: You asked the compiler to make a reference to const int.